# Why calling this function produces error "<function> is not a function or function pointer"?

Tags: c, function, scope, function-call

Seems like the function `qwertyInches()` should work but when I call it in `main()` it   gives me

> [Error] called object 'qwertyInches' is not a function or function pointer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// Global constant
const int MAX_LENGTH = 81;   // global constant for max input line length


void qwertyInches (char row[], double *inches, int x, double y) {
    int d;
    for (d = 0; d < strlen(row); d++) {
        if (x == row[d]) {
            *inches = *inches + y;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int count[256] = { 0 };
    int  letterCounter = 0;
    int qwertyCounter = 0;
    int homeRowCounter = 0;
    int dvorakCounter = 0;
    char qwertyHomeRow[23] = {"asdfghjkl;ASDFGHJKL:\"'" };
    char dvorakHomeRow[22] = {"aoeuidhtns-_AOEUIDHTNS"};
    double percentOfCharQwerty = 0.0;
    double percentOfCharDvorak = 0.0;
    char qwertyHomeRowInches[4] = {"ghGH"};
    char qwertyRowInches[46] = {"qweruiopQWERUIOP{[}]\ZzXx|CcVvNnMm<,>./?"};
    char qwertyNumberInches[25]= {"`~1!2@3#4$5%7&8*9(0)-_=+)"};
    char qwertyTAndYInches[4] = {"TtYy"};
    char num6Inches[2] = {"6^"};
    char dvorakHomeRowInches[4]= {"iIDd"};
    char dvorakRowInches[41] = {"\"<',.>PpGgCcRrLl?/:+=|:;QqJjKkBb\MmWwVvZz"};
    char dvorakYandFInches[4] = {"YyFf"};
    char dvorakNumberInches [25] = {"~`1!2@3#4$5%7&8*9()0{[]}"};
    double dvorakInches = 0.0;
    double qwertyInches = 0.0;


    /* loop counters */
    int k;
    int l;
    int d;
    /* file handle --- in this case I am parsing this source code */
    FILE *fp = fopen("newsample.txt", "r");

    /* a holder for each character (stored as int) */
    int c;

    /* for as long as we can get characters... */
    while((c=fgetc(fp))) {

        /* break if end of file */
        if(c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        else if (c == 32 || c == 10 || c == 9) {
            count[c]+=1;
        }
        /* otherwise add one to the count of that particular character */
        else {
            count[c]+=1;
            letterCounter++;
            for (l = 0; l < strlen(dvorakHomeRow); l++) {
                if (c == qwertyHomeRow[l]) {
                    qwertyCounter++;
                }
                if (c == dvorakHomeRow[l]) {
                    dvorakCounter++;
                }
            }
            qwertyInches(strlen(qwertyHomeRowInches) , &qwertyInches, c, .75 );

        }

    }


percentOfCharQwerty = (double) qwertyCounter / (double) letterCounter * 100;
percentOfCharDvorak = (double) dvorakCounter / (double) letterCounter * 100;

printf("Amount of Letters: %d\n", letterCounter);
printf("qwerty counter: %d\n", qwertyCounter);
printf("Dvorak counter: %d\n", dvorakCounter);
printf("Percent of qwerty letters %.2lf\n", percentOfCharQwerty);
printf("Percent of Dvorak letters %.2lf\n", percentOfCharDvorak);
printf("qwertyInches: %.2lf\n", qwertyInches);
printf("dvorakInches: %.2lf\n", dvorakInches);
/* close the file */
fclose(fp);
return;
}
```

Comment: Among the many answers, it also looks like you are passing in wrong parameters. You have `char row[]` are the first param but are passing in `strlen(qwertyHomeRowInches)`, which is an int;

Comment: @MichaelPickett I thing you meant `size_t`, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes I did. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `qwertyInches` local variable inside `main()` which shadows `qwertyInches()` function.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.1, *Scopes of identifiers* (*emphasis mine*)

> [....] If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (*the inner scope*) will end
>   strictly before the scope of the other entity (*the outer scope*). **Within the inner scope, the
>   identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer
>   scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**

***Solution:*** Change one of the names.

That said, the first argument of `qwertyInches()` function should be a `char *`, but you're passing a `size_t` (output of `strlen()`) which is plain wrong. Change that too.

Answer (score 2):

> when i call it in main it gives me this... [Error] called object 'qwertyInches' is not a function or function pointer.

And of course the compiler is right.  *Inside `main()`*, this declaration shadows the function declaration:

> ```
> double qwertyInches = 0.0;
> ```

Thus, in `main()`, `qwertyInches` refers to a local variable of type `double`, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

you're defining both `qwertyInches` as a variable AND a function.

```
void qwertyInches (char row[], double *inches, int x, double y) {
```

and

```
   double qwertyInches = 0.0;
```

Just change the name of one of the above. I generally give an "action" name to my functions, and a "thing" name to my variables.